# How to bind a property with Checkbox in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a simple class and I want to be able to bind the properties with the DataGrid.

```
public class Param : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isParamSelected;
    public bool Select
    {
        get { return isParamSelected; }
        set
        {
            isParamSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my .xaml code: I need to have checkboxes as my first column. I am not using DataGridCheckBoxColumn because it takes two clicks to check a box. With a simple CheckBox I can check it with a single click.

```
<DataGrid Name="AccumGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Select, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My problem is when I bind Select property to the CheckBox `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Select, Mode=TwoWay}" />`, it does not recognize it and gives me "Cannot resolve symbol 'Select'". I can check the box but it does not update the property Select. I have a List of Params `AccumList` with few objects in it. I also do `AccumGrid.ItemSources = AccumList` What am I missing here?

I have tried `<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" Binding="{Binding Path=Select, Mode=TwoWay}"/>` and that works perfectly alright but as mentioned before I do not want to double click to check a box.

Comment: You are sure binding datacontext for view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Binding's `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` (and note that `Mode="TwoWay"` is redundant, because that is the default for this property):

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Select, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Not sure however why this is necessary, as the `DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger` value of the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` of the `CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty` dependency property is already `PropertyChanged`.